# How to scatter copies of an object object on a plane

Tags: objects

[image]

Given a light stick object like the above, how do you scatter it on the ground like in the screenshot below?
[image]

Comment: to add to Chris' answer, you could also use particles

Comment: There is a lot of questions like that https://artisticrender.com/how-to-scatter-objects-with-geometry-nodes-in-blender/ ... Is there anything specific you need would like to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could e.g. use geometry nodes:

[image]

here a version with sun:

[image]